# Battery life of iPhone 4 reduced dramatically since iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, battery

Since I updated my iPhone 4 to iOS 7 (11A465), the battery began to drain really quickly, though the Bluetooth, GPS and the LTE are closed most of the time.

It makes me wonder whether there are operating system versions that are more economical with the battery usage.

Answer (score 1):

There of course are more power efficient operating systems for a couple of reasons.

1. Some operating systems take alot of space for themselves to actually run the system
2. Apps might not always be turned off but suspended, leaving them running

And one of the major battery eaters (not because of OS) is the screen. Turning down the brightness to half-way from full can save about 2-3 hours of battery (sometimes more).

A good solution to the background app problem is exiting the apps by pressing the home button twice. You will see the apps you have active. You can swipe up to exit the apps, and home button or tap on an app to go back to it. However that no longer works.

> Quitting apps is not the way to do it. The old 'slide it off the screen' does nothing whatsoever unless an app is hung etc. Backgrounded apps set to no refresh was the replacement for that old voodoo, since iOS 7

-Tetsujin

Basically, that solution used to be a thing, but now background apps do not seem to be the issue at all anymore.

---

Just as some extra information, Androids have custome ROMs (OS) that attempt on being more lightweight operating system clones of android. However custom ROMs have yet to exist on Apple phones

---

Sudden battery drain is also not only a software problem, but it could be a hardware problem too. To maintain battery health, make sure to charge with your native adapter (not other ones for different phones), as sometimes they have higher voltage, therefore harming the battery. If suspending apps does not resolve your battery problem, you might want to bring your phone for a battery checkup just in case.

---

And finally, to answer your question with battery packs, there are some good ones. You can get ones in a separate "power bank", where you connect your phone and charge, or you can get ones that are built-in to the iPhone case, like in the example below:

[image]

*Of course, there are also iPhone 4 cases, not just iPhone 6 ones.*

Comment: it doesn't answer my question. first of all the question wasn't about an android device, however the iphone 4 device. thus the mentioned is irrelevant. In addition, I asked for some specifig suggestions. The fact that there're battery packs that come as a phone-case and battery packs that are separated of the phone - it doesn't help much. I wanted to have a suggestion to a specific company/model.

P.S
still waiting about recommendation regarding the IOS battery-handling. apps that help to reduce the battery drain or maybe a bit older IOS that will improve the battery life...

Comment: I can edit to include that. I wanted to include information from Android that you can use on iOS too. I will look for some Greenify-like app. Also, either recommendations on external stuff, or shopping are off-topic on Ask Different

Comment: There are no apps to reduce battery usage, iOS doesn't work like that, apps are sandboxed. Best thing to do is switch off Background App Refresh in settings. Though, tbh, on such an old phone, the battery itself is most suspect.

Comment: @Tetsujin I would agree with the battery itself being the problem. Anyway, after a bit of research, I found that you can quit apps with the double-home screen completely, so I will edit

Comment: Quitting apps is not the way to do it. The old 'slide it off the screen' does nothing whatsoever unless an app is hung etc. Backgrounded apps set to no refresh was the replacement for that old voodoo, since iOS 7.

Comment: @Tetsujin I see. If you could add a good way to quit apps in a separate answer or edit then, as I don't have an iOS to play around with

Comment: You don't need to quit apps, that's my entire point.